# Why am I getting multiple OpenCL 'binaries' when I built my program for one device?

Tags: opencl, multi-gpu, dummy-data, ptx

I'm building an OpenCL program - using NVIDIA CUDA 11.2's OpenCL library (and its C++ bindings). After invoking `cl::Program::build()` successfully, for a single device (passing a vector with a single device index), I obtain the generated "binaries" sizes using: `built_program.getInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES>()`, which also succeeds, but gives me 3 values: A non-zero value and two zeros. When I print the first binary, I see the PTX code I expect.

My question: Why am I given two (empty) extra binaries?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the program is built for specific devices you specify (see [documentation for clBuildProgram](http://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL//sdk/2.2/docs/man/html/clBuildProgram.html)), the binaries are made available for each device in the *context*. In your case, you probably have three GPUs on your system; you built the program for a single device, so for one of the three devices, you see a non-empty PTX.

Confusing? Sure. Convoluted? Yes. But is it entirely senseless? Admittedly, not really.

Digging around a bit further, it seems this is even officially [documented](http://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL//sdk/2.2/docs/man/html/clGetProgramInfo.html) (emphasis mine):

> Returns an array that contains the size in bytes of the program binary (could be an executable binary, compiled binary or library binary) **for each device associated with program.** The size of the array is the number of devices associated with program. If a binary is not available for a device(s), a size of zero is returned.

Not every device for which you built, but every device associated with the program; which is probably every device in the OpenCL context with which you created the program.